# jdbc.SQLServerException on group by clause

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, criteria

While executing this code in my project:

```
Integer countObj = (Integer) ht.findByCriteria(criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount())).get(0);
```

I get the following exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column "PRODUCT_TASK.PRODUCT_TASK_ID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Here I am using two tables.

- `Product_task` with `product_task_id` as primary key
- `Product_info` with `product_info_id` as primary key

`product_info_id` is the foreign key for `Product_task`.

By executing that query I will get count.

I am getting this SQL query in my logs:

```
select count(*) as Count from PRODUCT_TASK pt inner join
PRODUCT_INFO pin on pt.PRODUCT_INFO_ID=pin.PRODUCT_INFO_ID
where pin.UPC like ? order by pt.PRODUCT_TASK_ID asc**
```

I know how to change SQL query (group by clause need to be there) but I don't know how to modify the Hibernate query in order to get the result.

Comment: Formatted the code into code block. Added exception in blockquote. Bullet pointed the tables. Made the title a little more informative

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [Projections's **.groupProperty()** method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#groupProperty(java.lang.String))  in your `Criteria`.

> **groupProperty**
>
> `public static PropertyProjection groupProperty(String propertyName)`
>
> A grouping property value

Your code would be like this:

```
Integer countObj = (Integer) ht.findByCriteria(criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()
.add(Projections.groupProperty("product_task_id"))))
.get(0);
```